# javascript promise callback

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I am calling a javascript function , which in turn calls a web service;The response of this service is used to call another function which also calls a service. At end of both services we set session attributes. This code gives no errors, but the callback gets called before the service has returned data. The main motive of this code is to set the session attributes before return of flow from this code, when the callback gets called before the service has returned values the session attributes are not set and the requirement of the code is not fulfilled.

```js
'use strict';

function close(sessionAttributes, fulfillmentState, message) {
    return {
        sessionAttributes,
        dialogAction: {
            type: 'Close',
            fulfillmentState,
            message : 'For security purpose answer these questions  '
        },
    };
}

function getSecurityQuestions(intentRequest, context, post_options, callback){
    const sessionAttributes = intentRequest.sessionAttributes || {};
    var policynumber = sessionAttributes.policynumber;
    var interactionID = sessionAttributes.interactionID;
    var body = "";
    var body2;
    const http = require('https');
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const post_data = JSON.stringify({"Purpose":"SecurityQuestions", "InteractionID":interactionID, "SearchStringAcctNum":policynumber});
    //ignores SSL
       process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
        var post_request = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(chunk)  {
                body += chunk;
                
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                context.done(body);
                resolve(body);
            });
            res.on('error', function(e) {
                reject(Error(e.message));
                context.fail('error:' + e.message);
            });
        });
        // post the data
        post_request.write(post_data);
        post_request.end();
    });
    
    callback(    promise.then((body) => {
        body2 = JSON.parse(body);
        sessionAttributes.question1 = body2.SecurityDetails[0].Question;

        close(sessionAttributes, 'Fulfilled');
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      })
    );  

}



function getInteraction(intentRequest, context, callback) {

    const slots = intentRequest.currentIntent.slots;
    var policynumber = "PA"+slots.PolicyNumber;
    var questionOne = slots.questionOne;
    var questionTwo = slots.questionTwo;
    const sessionAttributes = intentRequest.sessionAttributes || {};
    console.log("policy number : "+policynumber + "question 1 : "+questionOne + "question 2 : "+questionTwo);
    sessionAttributes.policynumber = policynumber;
    var body = "";
    var body2;
        // An object of options to indicate where to post to
        var post_options = {
            host: 'example.com',
            protocol: 'https:',
            port: '3000',
            path: '/hiddenPath',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
    const http = require('https');
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const post_data = JSON.stringify({"Purpose":"CreateInteraction"});
    //ignores SSL
       process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
        var post_request = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
            res.on('data', function(chunk)  {
                body += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                context.done(body);
                resolve(body);
            });
            res.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log("rejected here");
                reject(Error(e.message));
                context.fail('error:' + e.message);
            });
        });
    
        // post the data
        post_request.write(post_data);
        post_request.end();
    });
    
callback(    promise.then((body) => {
        body2 = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("interaction ID : "+body2.InteractionID);
        sessionAttributes.interactionID = body2.InteractionID;
        getSecurityQuestions(intentRequest, context, post_options, callback);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log('Promise rejected.');
        console.log(error.message);
      }));
}
 // --------------- Intents -----------------------

/**
 * Called when the user specifies an intent for this skill.
 */
function dispatch(intentRequest, context, callback) {
    const intentName = intentRequest.currentIntent.name;
    if (intentName === 'currIntent') {
        return getInteraction(intentRequest, context, callback);
    }
    throw new Error(`Intent with name ${intentName} not supported`);
}

// --------------- Main handler -----------------------
function loggingCallback(response, originalCallback) {
    console.log("logging callback called......");
        originalCallback(null, response);
}

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {

        dispatch(event, context, (response) => loggingCallback(response, callback));
    } catch (err) {
        callback(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: You're not returning the `promise` from `getValue` function.

Comment: why don't use request promise library instead

Answer (score 0):

You should resolve your promise only after the request ends.. Have updated your sample below. Hope it helps. Also, you were sending an invalid object as your post body. Fixed that as well.

```js
function getValue(context, post_options, callback) {

  var body = "";
  var body2;
  const http = require('http');

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // INVALID OBJECT
    //const post_data = JSON.stringify({"something"});
    const post_data = JSON.stringify({
      something: "something"
    });


    //ignores SSL
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
    var post_request = http.request(post_options, function(res) {

      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
        console.log("inside " + JSON.stringify(body));
        // DONT RESOLVE HERE, REQUEST IS NOT COMPLETE
        //resolve(body);
      });

      res.on('end', function() {
        context.done(body);
        //RESOLVE HERE INSTEAD
        resolve(body);
      });

      res.on('error', function(e) {
        reject(Error(e.message));
        context.fail('error:' + e.message);
      });
    });

    // post the data
    post_request.write(post_data);
    post_request.end();
  });

  promise.then((body) => {
    console.log("response data " + JSON.stringify(body));
    body2 = JSON.parse(body);
    callback(delegate(sessionAttributes, intentRequest.currentIntent.slots));

  }, (error) => {
    console.log('Promise rejected.');
    console.log(error.message);
  });

}
```

Comment: i made the changes, and the problem still persists. i replaced the post data body to something due to confidentiality.The error generated is that the function cannot find the callback function which is inside the promise block.

Comment: `The error generated is that the function cannot find the callback function which is inside the promise block.` Can you share the exact error? With stack trace?